# Modally presented UIViewController hides status bar, but doesn't show it again on dismiss

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, modalviewcontroller

So I have a view controller `modalVC` that I am instantiating from a storyboard and presenting modally via `[self presentViewController:modalVC animated:YES completion:nil]`.

The problem is that when the modal view is displayed, the status bar is hiding (which I actually want, even though I'm making no explicit instruction to do so), but when the modal controller is dismissed (via `[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil]`), the status bar is *remaining hidden*.

I reiterate, I'm not to my knowledge making any explicit command to hide the status bar. None of my view controllers are overriding `prefersStatusBarHidden`, and nowhere am I calling `setStatusBarHidden`. I assume it's just the default modal presentation doing this.

But why is my status bar not reappearing?

Comment: Did you try to present another one? Will status bar dissapear also? or is it happens only for this particular view?

Comment: I can try another, but it's a very simple view. It consists of a toolbar and another container view (that I'm not even filling yet).

Comment: Did you set wantsFullScreenLayout for your modal view to YES ?

Comment: No I'm not setting `wantsFullScreenLayout` anywhere, although it is a full-screen view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dismiss the modal using 
`dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES`, 
and call

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO withAnimation:YES];
```

before

```
dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES
```

to make sure the bar is drawn in the correct location (it could happen when you set `wantsFullScreenLayout` to `YES` on your modal view )

Answer (score 0):

I'm stupid. It turns out I was setting `statusBarHidden = YES` when the modal view was appearing.

Crisis averted!

Answer (score 0):

For others that may end up here *banging their heads on the wall* for hours, trying to figure why their status bar get's hidden, keep in mind that **if** `supportedInterfaceOrientations` **returns an invalid orientation**, say **goodbye** to your **status bar** on iPhone X devices.

In our case `supportedInterfaceOrientations` returned 0 (which is [not a valid UIInterfaceOrientationMask orientation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiinterfaceorientationmask)), but no errors no nothing. The only side effect was that the status bar was getting hidden after we presented another view controller modally.

I hope that saves someone.